# C - for loop ends early

Tags: c, function, file, for-loop

Full code: https://pastebin.com/NpspcJB8

```
FILE *fptr;

char regPlates[350][10]; // array of registration number plates, e.g. AA234BB

switch (userInput) {
      case 'a': // check available spaces

          ReadFromFile();

          CheckEmptySpaces();
      break;
}
```

The above code is part of what I have done for my assessment. What I am trying to do for this case in the `switch` statement is to check the number of available spaces in a car park from the file and from an array. This is how part of the file looks like:

```
Space: A1 Customer Name: a Registration number: a

Space: A2 Customer Name: e Registration number: e

Space: A3 Customer Name:  Registration number: 

Space: A4 Customer Name: g Registration number: g

Space: A5 Customer Name: h Registration number: h
```

Here is the content of the functions:

```
int ReadFromFile() {
    fptr=fopen("parking_spaces.txt", "r");
    if (fptr==NULL) {
        printf("Error! File does not exist");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 350; i++) {
        fscanf(fptr, "\nSpace: %s Customer Name: %s Registration number: %s\n", &parkingSpaces[i],  &otherInfo[i], &regPlates[i]);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}

void CheckEmptySpaces() {
    c = 350;
    for (i = 0; i < 350; i++) {
        if (strcmp(regPlates[i], "") != 0) {
            c-=1;
        }
    }
    printf("There are %d free parking spaces \n", c);  
}
```

The problem is, when the file looks like what I have linked, the code only considers the first two spaces occupied and the first two array indices, even though there are four parking spaces. If I add more cars to the car park, then the values for the parking spaces A4 and A5 become overwritten.

I believe that this may be a result of the `for` loop ending early, but I would like to know some other causes for this happening.

Comment: Line 3 doesn't fit the `scanf` pattern, it's missing the customer name and registration number.

Comment: You should use a regular expression for this rather than `fscanf()`.

Comment: ...so you should, at least,  look at the `fscanf` return value...

Comment: it's better to use some value to show empty spaces like "null" or 0 or something like that.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, I thought that scanf would be able to read this.

Comment: Nope.  `scanf()` patterns are not regular expressions.  They are matched linearly, without backtracking, and every field descriptor within must be matched before any following pattern characters are matched.  `%s` skips leading whitespace and matches a *whitespace-delimited* string;  it can never match an empty string.

Comment: Is it valid to have a blank name, but still have a registration number?

Comment: @Dmitri it might not be because I will only ask the user from the program for the customer's name